# "TS2585 and TS2304 errors while compiling TypeScript file with Axios"

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios

## **How can I resolve the following errors when trying to compile my TypeScript code using tsc index.ts?**

```
node_modules/axios/index.d.ts:75:3 - error TS1165: A computed property name in an ambient context must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.

75   [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[string, AxiosHeaderValue]>;
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/axios/index.d.ts:75:4 - error TS2585: 'Symbol' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to es2015 or later.

75   [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[string, AxiosHeaderValue]>;
      ~~~~~~

node_modules/axios/index.d.ts:75:24 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'IterableIterator'.

75   [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[string, AxiosHeaderValue]>;
```

## Directory image:

[image]

## Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "1-fetchdataapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.6"
  }
}
```

I tried installing the latest versions of packages, but the issue persisted.

Answer (score 8):

By installing @types/node the problem solved.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```